# Why is there not an article before the word "disease" in this context?

Tags: articles

I read a book which states:

> "Inheritence, age, gender, infectious agents, or behaviours, can all **cause disease.**"

Why is there not an article before **"disease"** in this case even though it's a countable noun?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Disease* can be **both** countable and uncountable.

In your sentence it is uncountable because it means illness as the state of being ill, not a particular disease of the body or mind.

Compare:

- *Chickenpox is **a** very common disease among children*. (this sentence is about a specific disease, one of many infectious diseases)
- *Starvation and disease have killed thousands of refugee*s. (in this case *disease* is uncountable as it means the concept of lack of good health)